# index.php added in url with virtualhost on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mamp, virtualhost

I created a virtualhost with MAMP. It works well when I go to example.dev. I just installed a wordpress on example.dev without any problems. When I display a page or a post, there is a /index.php which is added before the page name. For example : example.dev/**index.php**/pagename. 
I can not access example.dev/pagename, i have a 404 error. 
In permalink's options, it generates automatically `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`.
I selected `http://example.dev/example-article/` but it is still not working.

I have a htaccess at the root

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If somebody has an idea...

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

To this url `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` will work on Apache server add this rule to `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/?$ /$1/ [L]
```

Above the WordPress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Given that your .htaccess have the basic WordPress rules it would look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/?$ /$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress